# Azure App Service with Authentication Enabled silently logs in with previous credential after logout

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, easy-auth

I have an Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization configured to use to sign in with Microsoft (aka Easy Auth).  Everything works great.  However I'm confused about the logout behavior.  If I go to `myapp/.auth/logout` I am definitely logged out since I no longer see the `X-MS-CLIENT...` headers on requests.

Then I go to `/.auth/login/microsoftaccount` but instead of getting prompted for credentials I am automagically signed in with the previous account.  It is nice many times but I am trying to test users with different permissions.  If I start a new private browser I am prompted every time as I expect.

I must have missed something either at logout or a login parameter to enable a re-prompt.  Can someone help me understand what I missed here?

Easy Auth docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

Comment: I should note that Edge browser behaves as I expect.  Logging out, then logging in again prompts me to select the identity.  Chrome ... not so much.  Any ideas still appreciated.  However measured or far away.

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that the logout is working correctly. You are not prompt for login because of SSO.

Certain identity providers support what’s called “server-side logout”. AAD supports this, but MSA does not (at least not programmatically). Server-side logout ensures that you also terminate the SSO session, which is why logging out from an AAD app will always require the user to re-enter credentials.

If you want to login with different users, you can try to force a login prompt.

```
{site}/.auth/login/microsoftaccount?prompt=login
```

Comment: See my comment in my original q.  Edge behaves as I expect -- I get prompted for and can use any valid credential.  However Chrome just silently signs in with whatever last credential I used.  Only if I blast all my Chrome cookies do I get prompted again.  It seems like something is missing from the Azure Authentication docs about what do to after logout.  I haven't had a chance to trace the cookies before and after to see what Edge is doing that Chrome is not.

Comment: The suggestion in this answer did not work using Chrome